# Writing Unit Test framework for an Angular component library

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-test

I have an Angular component library already written without unit test cases. The components follow certain level of hierarchy. Each component (say TextComponent) inherits a common set of properties from a base class (say FormComponent having a property say backgroundcolor) which in turn inherits properties from another base class (say BaseComponent having a property say name). I want to write unit test cases for all the components in the library.

**What I have done so far**
Now, I am able to test properties on Text component in its individual spec file (properties specific to only TextComponent + common properties inherited from FormComponent). What I don't want to do is write same test cases for common properties for another component (say SelectComponent).

**What I want to achieve**
What I am looking for is probably writing a framework that takes care of testing all common properties for all components (there are 60+) and test cases for individual properties of a component can be written in its own spec file. Any suggestions will be really appreciated.

Comment: Please update your question with source code examples of what you find challenging to test. Share how you're components are inherited and explain why you can't easily test it.

Comment: A code example makes it easier for us to better understand the problem and provide a possible solution. A good online code editor in which you can make and example is https://stackblitz.com/.